# Canvas Zoom out Image Quality Loss

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I written a code for zooming and zoom-out the canvas image but if try to zoom the image more than once the quality of image is changing.
This is my code using canvas2image plugin i am converting canvas to normal image.

Can any body please suggest me is there any thing wrong way i am doing.

```
function imgZoom(operation) {
    var zoomImageObj = document.getElementById("originalImage");
    var zoomedCanvas = $("#zoomCanvasPreview")[0];
    var zoomedContext = zoomedCanvas.getContext("2d");

    var selectedImgWidth = $('#originalImage').width();
    var selectedImgHeight = $('#originalImage').height();

    $("#zoomCanvasPreview").attr("height", selectedImgHeight);
    $("#zoomCanvasPreview").attr("width", selectedImgWidth);

    var previewHeight = $("#zoomCanvasPreview").height();
    var previewWidth = $("#zoomCanvasPreview").width();

    var zoomFactor = $("#zoomFactor option:selected").val();

    // Making the zoomfactor string as float point then parsing for addition

    // zoomFactor values if user selected 5%(0.05), 10%(0.1), 15(0.15) &etc
    var zoomPercent = 1 + parseFloat(zoomFactor);

    if(operation == 'zoomIn') {
        newZoomWidth = Math.round(previewWidth *  zoomPercent) ;
        newZoomHeight = Math.round(previewHeight *  zoomPercent) ;
    } else if(operation == 'zoomOut'){
        newZoomWidth = Math.round( previewWidth / zoomPercent );
        newZoomHeight = Math.round( previewHeight / zoomPercent );
    }

    if( (newZoomWidth >= 0) && (newZoomHeight >= 0) )
    {
        $("#zoomCanvasPreview").attr("width", newZoomWidth);    
        $("#zoomCanvasPreview").attr("height", newZoomHeight);

        // Drawing the image to canvas
        zoomedContext.drawImage(zoomImageObj, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight, 0, 0, newZoomWidth, newZoomHeight );

        //return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var zoomedCanvas = $("#zoomCanvasPreview")[0];

        oImgConvertExt = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(zoomedCanvas, true);
        $("#originalImage").attr("src", oImgConvertExt.src);
        $("#originalImage").attr("style", "display: none; visibility: hidden; width: "+newZoomWidth+"px; height: "+newZoomHeight+"px;");
    } else {
        alert("Reached maximum zoom out limit");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Image quality will not get changed If you use Images of format .SVG
these image will never get distorted even if you zoom IN  or zoom OUT

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around quality loss if you use `canvas.drawImage()`.

Just zoom by changing the CSS `width` and `height` values. There won't be any quality loss then.

It is also a lot simpler to code...